# Python 2.7 Break function doesn't finish program

Tags: python, loops, break

I don't understand why the define gameover() is looped. As I think Break should break While, then define gameover() is completed. And nothing after it, it's mean the program should be terminated.
I think that it is possible to rewrite, but I want to understand what is wrong in precisely this code. Thank you.

```
import random
import sys

def play():
    print """\
    ************************************
    * "Guess the number" welcomes you! *
    *                                  *
    *        Difficulty Levels:        *
    *                                  *
    *  1 - Easy (you have 5 attempt)   *
    *  2 - Normal (you have 3 attempt) *
    *  3 - Hard (you have 1 attempt)   *
    *                                  *
    *             Let's go!            *
    ************************************
    """
    lvl = input("Select Difficulty Level: ")
    if lvl == 1:
        lvl = 5
    elif lvl == 2:
        lvl = 3
    elif lvl == 3:
        lvl = 1

    num = random.randrange(1,10)
    x = 0

    while num != x:
        if lvl == 0:
            print ("You lose.\n")
            gameover()
        else:
            x = input("Enter your number: ")
            if num > x:
                print ("It's bigger!\n")
            if num < x:
                print ("It's smaller!\n")
            pass
            lvl = lvl - 1

    print ("You win!")
    print num

def gameover():
    while True:
        restart = input("Would you like to play again? Please enter '1' for YES or '2' for NO: ")
        if restart==1:
            play()
        else:
            print "Thanks for playing!"
            break

def main():
    play()
    gameover()

main()
```

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem is.  The code acts exactly as I believe it should.

Comment: Is this Python 3? If so `restart` will never equal 1, as `input` returns a string.

Comment: It's doesn't seem to be Python 3 - there are a couple of non-function style `print`s.

Comment: No, it's 2.7. I just started to learn it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the losing case, `gameover()` is called from within `play()`. `break` does indeed cause `gameover()` to return, however, execution returns to the following line in `play()` - which is within its own loop. You could fix this by simply calling `return` instead of calling `gameover()` in `play()`:

```
    while num != x:
        if lvl == 0:
            print ("You lose.\n")
#            gameover()
            return
        else:
            .
            .
            .
```

This should fix the problem.

Comment: Thank you! It works correctly now. If I understood, now this happens: while -> return -> |end of define i.e. play() -> gameover()| -> end? I don't quite understand the principle of the Return, will read more about this.